# Akka logback actor appender

Tags: scala, akka, logback

I am trying to write an appender for [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) that sends all logging events to an [akka](/questions/tagged/akka) actor which maintains a list of remote actors that monitor the system.

The appender seemed relatively easy at first:

```
class MonitoringAppender extends AppenderBase[ILoggingEvent] {
  def mon = Main.system.actorSelection("akka://Backend/user/MonitorEndpoint")
  override def append(event: ILoggingEvent): Unit = {
    mon ! Log(event.toString)
  }
}
```

`Main` is the object that starts up the system and therefore has a reference to the `ActorSystem`. The problem I have is that `Main` doesn't seem to be loaded when the first log messages come in and the whole application crashes.

I tried to delay the usage of `Main` as far as possible by making `mon` a `def`.

Is there the possibility, that `Main` can add this appender after the application has started or have this appender deactivated and activate it once the system is ready to avoid this issue?

Comment: Are you using Akka's built in logging facility in your code?  If so, why not just add another logging event handler to the config (a custom one you write) and listen to the log stream that way?

Comment: @cmbaxter well... it seems like often the solution is much simpler than expected. That works perfectly. Thank you! Do you want to post an answer or should I post my implemented solution?

Comment: I added an answer.  Feel free to add a comment to it if you feel you have more details to include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better option here is to listen to the logging event stream as long as you are using Akka's logging facility.  If you read the docs [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.5/scala/logging.html), specifically the section on Loggers, it should give you a good idea of how to add your custom logging handler into the logging config.